# How do we encourage people to NOT put tags in their titles?

Tags: discussion, newbies, tags

I do rather a lot of editing (I'm not sure how much, but I don't have my copy editor badge yet). By and large the main thing I notice and edit is people putting tags in their titles. On Stack Exchange, that's as unnecessary as signing your posts: everywhere your question appears on the site (barring links), its tags are also right there. We can tell whether you're asking about XNA or Unity or Unreal because right beside the question we can see [xna](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xna) or [unity](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unity) or [unreal](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unreal).

There are question titles like: [How to create an extensible rope in Box2D?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/40104/2698) Those are fine, it's a fluid sentence. The case I'm talking about are questions like these (which I've edited) where there's a tag just sitting in the title to be there:

- [cocos2d rotate sprite to touch](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/posts/40106/revisions)
- [[multiplayer]mouse based movement ?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/posts/40111/revisions)
- [Unreal Editor (Unreal Tournament 3) Why does the loaction of my vehicle spawner change when I open a matinee?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/posts/40095/revisions)

What can we do so our users won't feel the need to tag their question titles like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What can we do so our users won't feel the need to tag their question
>   titles like this?

When you edit the post, leave a comment explaining why you removed the tag from the title. There's probably a meta post, either here or from the StackExchange meta, that explains why redundantly including the tag is a bad thing -- you could link to that, I'll see if I can find it.

This will likely only work well with users who stick around, as opposed to the ones that ask one-off questions and never really return, but there's not much to be done about them anyway. Unfortunately I think they're the majority of the population that produces "bad" questions in one form or another since they don't necessarily know this isn't a forum.

Answer (score -4):

You could teach them grammar. Seriously though, I'm not sure this could or even should change. The main tag in title should stay. At least until tags aren't visible in Google search since it allows to quickly identify if a post is somewhat on-topic to what I'm trying to find.

I find myself liking the construct, in fact. Let's look at it this way: this is a left-to-right language so I'd read it in that direction. First words are tags that let me know if I need to go further. Less words = faster filtering. What follows would be the main point of the question, and again - the less grammar I have to parse, the better the experience is for me. I strongly dislike all "how to", "a/an/the", "of/in/with.." when I'm searching for an answer.

Comment: I'm not proposing to remove the main tag from the page title (which is incredibly useful for showing results in search engines). I'm talking about people who write out their question's title _with tags in it_ unnecessarily.

Comment: @JonathanHobbs The examples are somewhat misleading then. The only difference I see is ".. in [tag]" vs. "[tag] ..".

Comment: The examples are exactly what I am talking about, there is nothing misleading about them. Note that the 'cocos2d', the '[multiplayer]' and the 'Unreal Editor (Unreal Tournament 3)' are not the tag that is added to the beginning of the page title so that tags show up in search results. They are a tag written in the question title by the asker, which is unnecessary.

Comment: @JonathanHobbs Ah, the *page* title. Well, it just so appears that few people actually look at it or care about what's written there. When the tab is fighting with 20 more tabs in my browser, this exercise proves to be highly counterproductive.

Comment: We're having a complete communication breakdown here. Since we're now both speaking in chat, [I'll leave a permalink to our conversation here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6522301#6522301).